# PC not powering on anymore on new build?

Tags: computer-building

I built a new pc with specs:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X
CPU FAN: STOCK FAN
RAM: 16GB CORSAIR VENGEANCE
GPU: RX 580
MOBO: MSI B450M Micro ATX
CASE: COOLERMASTER Q300
PSU: CX 550M

At start it was working fine i installed windows and everything, but i then realised little glitchy dots appearing on my screen, I realised it was my GPU so I took it out and put it back in properly (maybe i placed it loosely) then i got a black screen followed by a full glitchy screen which then turned off my pc. Second day i turned pc on and for like 3 seconds i was on desktop but then it shut down and now I can't turn it back on.

Iv'e tried to take out the graphics card and plug HDMI in voa mobo with the card out and unplugged, but still not working, but that might be the cpu which has not integrated graphics right?

but why is my pc not powering on, have i just wasted $1000?

Please help

Comment: Take it to a repair shop. This is not the kind of issue that can be diagnosed from a list of build components.

Comment: i just realised it was the power supply it came faulty, i did the pin test and the fan was not moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power supply was faulty. The fan didn't move when it was tested with the pin test.

Comment: how did you know this? i did test it and the fan didn't move.